# Angular/Typescript: How to return enum key instead of value in a key-value pair?

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have the interfaces `Meal` and `Mealplan` with data coming from an api. Each Mealplan consists of key-value pairs, where the Keys are stored in enum `Weekday`. So, each Mealplan contains one Meal for each weekday.

```
export interface Meal {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export enum Weekday {
  Monday = 0,
  Tuesday = 1,
  Wednesday = 2,
  Thursday = 3,
  Friday = 4
}

export interface Mealplan {
  id: number;
  mealsPerWeek: { [key in Weekday]: Meal };
}
```

Now I have a reactive form where I want to display the different **meals** of **mealsPerWeek** and return the **meal** and the **weekday** with **[ngValue]**. This will be important to delete a specific **meal** from **mealsPerWeek**

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let meal of mealplan?.mealsPerWeek | keyvalue: returnZero"
          [ngValue]="{meal: meal.value, weekday: meal.key}"
          [label]="essen.value.name"></option>
</select>
```

The Problem now is, that the value of **weekday** now is the String like "Monday" -  How do I return the number value like 0 for Monday instead? I expected something like `meal.key[key]` to work, but it does not.

```
console.log(this.form.meal.value.weekday) // "Monday", but expected 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an example on the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkx1fc) that works perfectly

```
 mealplan: Mealplan = {
    id: 10,
    mealsPerWeek: {
      [Weekday.Monday]: { id: 0, name: 'Monday meal' },
      [Weekday.Tuesday]: { id: 1, name: 'Tuesday meal' },
      [Weekday.Wednesday]: { id: 2, name: 'Wednesday meal' },
      [Weekday.Thursday]: { id: 3, name: 'Thursday meal' },
      [Weekday.Friday]: { id: 4, name: 'Friday meal' },
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can just use `console.log(Weekday[this.form.meal.value.weekday])` to achieve what you want.

I however recommend to always use enums with strings as values, e.g.:

```js
enum Weekday {
  Monday = "Monday",
  Tuesday = "Tuesday",
  Wednesday = "Wednesday",
  Thursday = "Thursday",
  Friday = "Friday"
}
```

Comment: I will try it - thank you! - Yeah, but the problem is that in the backend and for api calls, the enums with number values are required.